# Polymorphic relation "undefined method `comments' for #<Post..." error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I tried to create a simple posts-comments relation. Here is my model:
Here is my Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is my Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

And here is the schema that got generated:

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "comments", ["commentable_type", "commentable_id"], name: "index_comments_on_commentable_type_and_commentable_id", using: :btree
```

All seems good and well. But when I do in the console:

```
 Post.last().comments()
```

I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `comments' for #<Post:0x0000000357e2b8>
    Did you mean?  committed!
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
            from (irb):36
```

I am completely stuck! This surely has to be some kind of a silly typo.

Comment: How are you getting to the console? Are you using `rails c` from the root of your rails app?

Comment: @ReggieB Yes, I use `rails c` from the root. And if I type `#<Post id: 12, title: "dsadasdasd", body: "asdasdsa", user_id: 4, created_at: "2016-11-26 14:28:37", updated_at: "2016-11-26 14:28:37">` which is just a rendom post I created.

Comment: Have you restarted or reloaded console after adding this code?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, turns out my IDE was messing around with the files in weird ways, so that the actual code that was run was missing some bits. Closing all the files and re-saving resolved the issue.